# How do I set up Continuous Integration for my Github project?

Tags: github

I saw for some popular projects that Travis CI is included. Is there a setting in GitHub that adds this to the project, if not how is this possible?

Comment: Travis isn't the only CI service available for Github projects. I personally prefer Codeship

Comment: What type of project is this, by the way?

Comment: For the sake of the question it's a library for use with the Facebook API but the question itself was really a seed from http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43637/github

Answer (score 2):

To set up Continuous Integration on GitHub, you need to have an account with a CI provider, such as [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) or TravisCI. Then, to list it in your GitHub README, just add a link like the following:

```
<img src="https://circleci.com/gh/circleci/circle.png?circle-token=9d08f2d7a27f378d18681e517a0723518f478df3">
```

[image: CircleCI status badge]

Magic!